# Total available physical memory from /proc/meminfo not adding up

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, memory, architecture

I'm trying to account for the available physical memory on a Linux box through `/proc/meminfo` (output provided below). Accounting for current free memory, user-space physical usage, kernel data structures including those vmalloc-ed, huge pages etc I'm coming up short by ~5 GB. This is what meminfo gives me at the moment:

```
# cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal: 362816744 kB
MemFree: 2230348 kB
Buffers: 433636 kB
Cached: 814628 kB
SwapCached: 20688 kB
Active: 723172 kB
Inactive: 539364 kB
Active(anon): 369736 kB
Inactive(anon): 14936 kB
Active(file): 353436 kB
Inactive(file): 524428 kB
Unevictable: 2080 kB
Noswap 292435456 kB
Mlocked: 2080 kB
SwapTotal: 4190964 kB
SwapFree: 4072560 kB
Dirty: 640 kB
Writeback: 0 kB
AnonPages: 292440380 kB
Mapped: 144904 kB
Shmem: 129772 kB
Slab: 568552 kB
SReclaimable: 483816 kB
SUnreclaim: 84736 kB
KernelStack: 13776 kB
PageTables: 785532 kB
NFS_Unstable: 0 kB
Bounce: 0 kB
WritebackTmp: 0 kB
CommitLimit: 156197224 kB
Committed_AS: 402420112 kB
VmallocTotal: 34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed: 17872740 kB
VmallocChunk: 34142133244 kB
HardwareCorrupted: 0 kB
HugePages_Total: 28713
HugePages_Free: 14352
HugePages_Rsvd: 0
HugePages_Surp: 0
Hugepagesize: 2048 kB
DirectMap4k: 6144 kB
DirectMap2M: 2017280 kB
DirectMap1G: 367001600 kB
```

How I accounted for current memory state: MemFree + Buffers + Cached + SwapCached + AnonPages + Mapped + Slab + KernelStack + PageTables + vmalloced memory + huge pages

Since VmallocUsed throws up memory usage of external physical devices remapped (using ioremap) in addition to physical memory, to get the actual physical memory component I did the following:

```
echo "( $(cat /proc/vmallocinfo | grep vmalloc | awk '{print $2}' | paste -s -d "+") )/ 1024" | bc
```

(as suggested [here](http://enakai00.hatenablog.com/entry/20110906/1315315488)).

So vmalloc physical memory consumption works out to be 826376 KB.

Huge pages = 28713 * 2048 Kb = 58804224 KB

With all this, I'm coming up with ~ 5G worth of unaccounted-for memory (comparing with MemTotal).

If there is something I have not accounted for here and could explain the gap, please do let me know.